# Can't deploy to HoloLens emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, hololens

Just created default project **Holographic DirectX11 App (Universal Windows)** in VS2015 Update 2 with HoloLens emulator installed and hit F5.

HoloLens emulator starts loading, but at some point

> *The emulator is unable to connect to the device operating system: The emulator is unable to determine the host IP address, which is used to communicate with the guest virtual machine. Some functionality might be disabled.*

[image: Screenshot]

I can start emulator from Hyper-V Manager and connect to it, but the screen is not responding to mouse clicks and stuck with start menu (same picture in emulator window if I start it from VS2015, but with this error message at the beginning):

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am encountering the exact same problem. Even following the delete/recreate switch on hyper-v doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @superbre I've updated answer a bit - give it a try may be it could be helpful with HoloLens as well cause sounds similar to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, some "standard" clean up did the thing:

1. Open **Hyper-V Manager**
2. Remove all *Windows Phone* and *HoloLens* virtual machines (they will be recreated later)
3. Click on **Virtual Switch Manager...** link in the *Actions* panel on the right and remove all virtual switches
4. Reboot (I did it "just in case", may not be required)
5. Open any HoloLens project in **VS2015** and hit **F5** - this should re-created new virtual machine for HoloLens and successfully deploy the app.

### * Update *

It seems there is a bit more appropriate place for questions like this in the future - official [Questions and Answers](https://forums.hololens.com/categories/questions-and-answers) forum.

### * Update 2 *

It may be related, so I'll just leave [this link](http://www.resolvinghere.com/sm/uwpsdkwindows-10-phone-emulators-no-longer-working.shtml) here (It did help me with very similar problem with Windows Phone emulator in the past).

Quoting the important part from the link above:

> Here is my solution and it work well for me:
>
> 1. open hyper-v as admin, open virtual switch manager, create a new virtual switch with "**Internal**", use the default name or any name you want, and save
> 2. open virtual switch manager again, and you will see the "**Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch**", copy the name "**Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch**" and change this switch to another name(whatever you want, I just add "**1**" to the following string like: **Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch 1**), and open your new added switch in the step 1, rename it to "**Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch**" (don't change or missing any string), save
> 3. open virtual switch manager again, and now you can delete the old "**Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch 1**" switch
> 4. open system network settings, adapter settings, you will see "**vEthernet (Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)**" is enable now, and the old one "**vEthernet (New Virtual Switch)**" is disabled which will not be used.
>
> in VS, just run and deploy to a emulator, have fun.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the

> The emulator is unable to connect to the device operating system: The emulator is unable to determine the host IP address, which is used to communicate with the guest virtual machine. Some functionality might be disabled.

problem by:

1. Opening the Hyper-V Manager
2. Opening the virtual switch manager
3. Selecting "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch"
4. Changing connection type from "Private network" to "Internal network"