# Consuming a WCF Service working with Hololens Emulator

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I am working in a LAN with Hololens Emulator consuming a WCF service. 
With Mobile Emulator 10.0.xxx I am able to stablish communication without problem. 
As soon as I change my Emulator to HoloLens Emulator(10.0.11082.1039) I receive an exception when trying to establish communication:
"**No IPEndpoints were found for host 192.168.0.16**"

The IP from the machine that have the WCF host in local network is "192.168.0.16" and it works with a different emulator

The capabilities in package.appmanifest I have enabled Private Networks and Internet capabilities.

In hyper-v the virtual switch of Hololens emulator is assigned to "Windows phone Emulator Internal Switch" the same as the the Mobile 10.xx Emulator.

I have followed also the steps described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323562/cant-deploy-to-hololens-emulator) with no success.

It seems there is an internal Hololens Emulator that block my connection.( this is just guessing)

Anyone have an additional idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it is not WCF. The problem is the HOlolens emulator and localhost. You should have 2 different machines to test it.